# Linear program with an additional second-degree utility term

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming

I would like to solve a problem obtained from a LP by adding a second degree term to its utility.

A simple example would be the following (with $c_i > 0$):
$$ \min xy - c_1 z_1 - c_2 z_2  
   \\ \textrm{s.t. } 
      x = z_1 + c_3, 
   \\ y = z_2 + c_4, 
   \\ x, y \geq 0. $$

I believe the problem cannot be converted into a geometric program (due to negative coefficients) nor a mixed linear geometric program (as the variables are not partitioned).

I tried to obtain a convex problem by introducing new variables $X := \log x, Y := \log y$ for
$$ \min t - c_1 z_1 - c_2 z_2 \\
   \textrm{s.t. } 
    t \geq e^{X+Y},  \\
    e^X = z_1 + c_3, \\
    e^Y = z_2 + c_4. $$
I thought about relaxing the equalities ($e^X \leq z_1 + c_3$, $e^Y \leq z_2 + c_4$) and compensate with a penalty term in the utility -- but I stuck here.

Is there an efficient way to solve such problem?

Comment: @batwing Maybe I'm missing something here -- xy is not concave in the first quadrant.

Comment: Oops, yes, you are correct, xy is not concave in the first quadrant.

Comment: There are a number optimizers available for nonconvex QPs. Maybe you should take a look at those.